# Make a 2d list in class 1, fill it in class 2 and use it in class 3

Tags: c#, class, uwp, nested-lists

As the title suggests, I have made/initialized/whatever a 2D list in Class 1, I fill it with stuff in class 2 and am trying to use its contents in class 3.

However, after filling the list in class 2 (where I have confirmed it has been filled), when calling the method in class 3 where the class is to be used, it is simply empty and I have no clue why.

Class 1

```
class class1
{
    public List<List<String>> playerInfo = new List<List<String>>();
    //it's a 2D list but as far as I know that shouldn't be a problem
```

Class 2

```
public sealed partial class class2: Page
{
    class1 host = new class1();

    private void joinButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (host.playerInfo.Count() <= 4)
        {

            //fill list
```

It seems to go OK up to this point. If I do a Count it shows it contains 2 elements, cool.

Class 3

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    GameHost host = new GameHost();

    public void Init()
    {

        if (host.playerInfo.Count() >= 2)
        {
            //Do stuff
         }
    }
}
```

Yet here the list is simply empty. The Count simply returns 0.

What could this be?

If my example here is not very clear, let me know, I'm not very good with this Stack Overflow thing yet.

Comment: Can you please add to your question description how you transfer the Class1 instasce to MainPage?

Comment: Sounds like a class design gone bad. Re-evaluate whether your class design can be improved. It certainly should be. And if you want to get better with this *"Stack Overflow thing"*, take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: Does joinButton_Click ever actually run?

Comment: You are creating two separate instances of your class1 each with its own separate list, which is why it is empty. Looks like it should be a static class, or rethink your class design as IInspectable suggests.

Comment: I would suggest you put your 2D Class in App.xaml.cs, and then use it using App.playerInfo in all the classes where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, the common root cause for that is overriding the list reference.
See the simple example below:

```
static void Main()
{
            List<int> mainList = new List<int>();
            UpdateList(mainList);
            Console.WriteLine(mainList.Count); // prints 0
}

private static void UpdateList(List<int> numbers)
{
            numbers = new List<int>();
            numbers.Add(1);
            numbers.Add(2);
            Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count); // prints 2
}
```

The list reference is transferred in the UpfdateList function. Once you executed the first line in UpfdateList with the new keyword, you lost the reference to the list from the main and now the referrence is to the new list created in UpfdateList.

To fix it, don't override the list reference:

```
private static void UpdateList(List<int> numbers)
{
                //numbers = new List<int>(); remove that
                numbers.Add(1);
                numbers.Add(2);
                Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count); // prints 2. 'numbers' still holds the reference the the list from the main 
}
```

Also, make sure you are using the same instance of Class1 in Class2 and Class3.

Comment: But I'm not even referencing the list twice, I create the list in class 1 and that's it. There is no  `numbers = new List<int>();` to remove because there isnt one besides in class 1. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Daan, Is it possible that you are using different instance of Class1 in Class3?

Comment: @Daan, so it make sense that updating the list won't be reflected in the new instance used by Class 3. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create a new instance in the `MainPage` Class. This instance has no values in the list. You could simply pass the instance into the `Init` method as parameter:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{    
    public void Init(GameHost host)
    {    
        if (host.playerInfo.Count() >= 2)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use the `GameHost` instance throughout the entire `MainPage` class you can also pass it through the constructor and initialize the field like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    GameHost host;

    public MainPage (GameHost _host)
    {    
        host = _host;
    }
}
```

Now it becomes usable in the class with all the initialized values that you had before.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    GameHost host;

    public MainPage (GameHost _host)
    {    
        host = _host;
    }

    public void Init(GameHost host)
    {    
        if (host.playerInfo.Count() >= 2) // now it should have the desired items
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

Initialize 2D List in `App.xaml.cs on App Launch`

```
private static List<List<String>> _playerInfo;
public static List<List<String>> PlayerInfo
{
    get
    {
        return (_playerInfo == null) ? new List<List<string>>() : _playerInfo;
    }
    set { _playerInfo = value; }
}
```

Now there is no need for class 1.

`class2` will be

```
public sealed partial class class2 : Page
{
    private void joinButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.PlayerInfo.Count <= 4)
        {
            // Fill your List Here
        }
    }
}
```

And `MainPage` will be

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (App.PlayerInfo.Count >=2)
        {
            // Do Stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally I would have `public List<List<String>> playerInfo = new List<List<String>>();` and then `playerInfo.Add(new List<String>());` to add a list in the first index of the main List. How would I go about (dynamically) adding lists to the one I initialize in App.xaml.cs? Because the way I mentioned above does not seem to be working (`.Count()` returns 0) :(

Comment: @Daan, In your `onActivated` in `App.xaml.cs`, you can do `playerInfo.Add(new List());` so you will have your list when initialized. And then you can play around with.